# Create my own shortcuts in RubyMine

Tags: intellij-idea, rubymine, rubymine-7

I know `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`.` will add `<%= %>` to your html.erb views. But can I make my own definitions?

For example, can I create something like this...

`Ctrl`+`Shift`+`b` to add `binding.pry` in a controller file?

Comment: As I'm aware of, you can not create an own shortcut. I can recommend you to use Macros: https://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/help/using-macros-in-the-editor.html

Answer (score 0):

As correctly noted by @kootli, you can record a macro and assign a keyboard shortcut for it. If the features of macros are not enough for you, you can write a plugin for RubyMine. Plugins are written in Java; see [here](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/PluginDevelopment) for plugin development documentation.